# SystemIndex Catlog Query is not searching the content of a document

Tags: c#, .net, windows-search

I have below query for searching the local system for the given search term. The below query is only searching the given search term in the file title and not from the content of the file. It is only searching content of a file from a .txt document and not from .doc and .pdf documents.It looks very weird. Kindly help.

```
SELECT "System.ItemName", "System.ItemFolderPathDisplay", "System.ItemTypeText", "System.ItemDate", "System.Kind", "System.ItemUrl" FROM "SystemIndex" WHERE CONTAINS(System.Search.Contents,'"SearchTerm"')  AND (System.FileName LIKE '%.doc' OR System.FileName LIKE '%.txt' OR System.FileName LIKE '%.xls' OR System.FileName LIKE '%.docx' OR System.FileName LIKE '%.xlsx' OR System.FileName LIKE '%.ppt' OR System.FileName LIKE '%.pptx' OR System.FileName LIKE '%.pdf')  AND Contains(System.Kind, 'document') ORDER BY System.FileName ASC
```

Thanks a lot for your help and time in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
CONTAINS('\"" + Searc + "*\"')
```